# FetchXML nvarchar returns nothing - Custom Report for CRM

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm, nvarchar, fetchxml

I am trying to get data from Dynamics CRM 2013 for a custom report using FetchXML.

I "converted" the following SQL Query to FetchXML using this page: http://www.sql2fetchxml.com/

SQL:

```
SELECT
accountidname,
billto_line1,
billto_postalcode,
billto_city,
invoicenumber,
name,
description
FROM FilteredInvoice 
WHERE invoiceid = @invoiceid
```

FetchXML:

```
<fetch mapping="logical">
  <entity name="invoice">
    <attribute name="accountidname" />
    <attribute name="billto_line1" />
    <attribute name="billto_postalcode" />
    <attribute name="billto_city" />
    <attribute name="invoicenumber" />
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="description" />
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="invoiceid" operator="eq" value="@invoiceid" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Both, "accountidname" and (e.g.) "billto_line1" are NVARCHAR(4000) and both contain data, but if I try to execute the query (e.g. in the "Query Designer" in Visual Studio) only the data of "billto_line1" is shown, not the data of "accountidname".

Since both fields "accountidname" and "billto_line1" are of the same type (nvarchar(4000)) and contain information in the database (I checked it with the "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio") I am wondering why I can only receive the information from one of those two.

This has happend with many different fields of the type NVARCHAR - some are displayed correctly, while some are not - and I have no idea why.

I would be very pleased if somebody could give me a hint :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accountidname` is on the Views, not the actual tables, in SQL. It is not a field on the `invoice` entity and therefore will not return any information in a FetchXml request.

You should be able to retrieve the Account's name by using `accountid` - I don't remember in SSRS how the `Name` property of an `EntityReference` is surfaced but it should be available.

The FetchXml converter is good at converting SQL SELECT's to FetchXml format and converting joins. It will not validate that the SQL fields are available in FetchXml - that could only be done by accessing the metadata of the CRM Org.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response (and sorry for my late replay - I was out of the office for a few days). Your explanation makes sense and since I started accessing the actual tables (not only the views) everything seems to work fine. Thank you - you made me (and my boss) happy :)